# Will Ignite Queue's removeAll work properly in multithreading?

Tags: ignite

We are trying to remove data from IgniteQueue in parallel using multithreading.

Below is the code that is called in individual threads.

```
def dequeue(array: Array[Row]): Unit = {
  val icfg= new IgniteConfiguration
  icfg.setClientMode(true)
  val ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(icfg)
  val igniteQueue:IgniteQueue[Row] = ignite.queue("Ignite", 0, new CollectionConfiguration)
  igniteQueue.removeAll(array)
}
```

Dequeueing is not happening properly.

Do I need to change the configuration?

Testing:

Queue count: 7588

Instead of multithreading we implemented **looping** for testing the removeAll **sequentially.**

```
dataFrame.take(3).foreach(row => {
    var array = /*array forming logic*/
    dequeue(array)
})
```

Iteration 1 : 166

Post removeAll Queue Size : 7422

Iteration 2 : 192

Post removeAll Queue Size : 7230

Iteration 2 : 185

Post removeAll Queue Size : 7045

Now in **Multithreading**

```
dataFrame.take(3).foreach(row => {
    var array = /*array forming logic*/
    val dequeueThread: ThreadDequeue = new ThreadDequeue(array)
    pool.submit(dequeueThread)
})
```

ThreadDequeue class will have the dequeue method.

Thread 1 : 166

Post removeAll Queue Size : 7416

Thread 2 : 192

Post removeAll Queue Size : 7414

Thread 2 : 185

Post removeAll Queue Size : 7259

**When executed sequentially the dequeue is happening fine. But in multithreading the count dequeued is not matching.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are the observed and expected behaviors?
What do you imply by improper dequeueing?

Comment: The Size of the queue after dequeue remains the same. Meaning no rows are getting dequeued. Expectation: All threads should remove rows from the queue in parallel.

Comment: I think you should provide more information. Ideally, a standalone unit tests that reproduces the behavior and fails with some assertions. In this case some one will be able to easily tell whether assertions are wrong, or there is  a bug in Ignite. Right now the problem is very vague.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the described behavior. I would agree with Valentin that a reproducer or a unit test is required to proceed.

Comment: Sorry. Edited the post and provided manual testing results for sequential dequeue and multithreaded dequeue. Thanks

Comment: How and where are you measuring the queue size in the multithreaded case. It looks like the values are some in-progress values.  
Could you wait until all the threads complete its work and then check if the resulting number of removed entries equals to the sum of (166 + 192 + 185 = 543)?